# A confusion the definition of a function when proving split monic(split epic) implies injective (surjective)

Tags: functions, logic, category-theory, proof-explanation, set-theory

I had this confusion when I read proofs of split-epic morphism implies surjective (in the category of sets) and split-monic morphism implies injective (in the full sub-category of sets consisting of all nonempty sets).

The problem is about the definition of a "function" here. Let $\phi:A\longrightarrow B$ be an injective function between two nonempty set $A,B$. I want to construct a "left inverse'' $\psi:B\longrightarrow A$ such that $\psi\circ\phi=id_{A}$. The proof I read goes as follows:

> Define $\psi:\phi(A)\longrightarrow A$ as follows. Let $b\in\phi(A)$, as $\phi$ is injective (so bijective onto $\phi(A)$), there exists a unique $a\in A$ such that $\phi(a)=b$, and we define $\psi(b):=a$. We now extend $\psi$ to $B\longrightarrow A$ by defining $\psi(b):=a_{0}$ for all $b\in B\setminus\phi(A)$ and for some $a_{0}\in A$.

Does uniqueness of the preimage matter here to justify that $\psi$ is well-defined? I used to think that it matters, because the uniqueness of preimage ensures that $\psi(b)$ will not have two possible values. However, the proof of split-epic implies surjective uses the same construction, but for this time we do not have the uniqueness in play.

Let $\phi:A\longrightarrow B$ be a surjective between two nonempty set $A,B$. This time, I want to construct a "right inverse" $\psi:B\longrightarrow A$ such that $\phi\circ\psi=id_{B}$. The proof then goes in an exactly the same way:

> As $\phi$ is surjective, $\phi(A)=B$, so we directly define $\psi:B\longrightarrow A$ as follows. For each $b\in B$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $\phi(a)=b$ and we define $\psi(b):=a$.

Well, in this case, the preimage is not necessarily unique. Is this $\psi$ well-defined? If it is, why do we even care about the uniqueness in the first proof?

If the uniqueness does not matter, then the first proof basically can be applied to any function: you split $B$ into $\phi(A)$ and $B\setminus\phi(A)$, and $\phi:A\longrightarrow\phi(A)$ is surjective, so the second proof applies, and then everything in $B\setminus\phi(A)$ will be mapped to a single element in $A$. So, every function in the full sub-category of sets consisting of all non-empty sets will be split-epic and split-monic (I don't consider the empty function and empty set here to make things easier). So...I am really confused.

**Edit:**

I am gonna re-clarify Ted's answer so perhaps someone gets the same confusion can have two explanations (the same though) as a reference. Ted has made it very clear.

The reason is that in the first proof you want to define $\psi:B\longrightarrow A$ such that $\psi(\phi(a))=a$, and you define $\psi$ in terms of the preimage. In other words, if $a,a'\in A$ are such that $\phi(a)=b=\phi(a')$, then $\psi(\phi(a))=a'$ can be true. It does not affect the fact that $\psi$ is well-defined because you can simply define $\psi(b):=a$ by choosing the specific $a$ (so you don't have two images), but then $\psi(\phi(a'))=a$, because $\phi(a')=b$ as well.

This does not happen to the second case, because you want to define $\psi:B\longrightarrow A$ such that $\phi(\psi(b))=b$. The definition goes the same, and for each $b\in B$, we can again specific the choice of $a\in A$ such that $\phi(a)=b$ and define $\psi(b):=a$. This time it does not matter anymore because you start with $b$, then you go to a specific $a$, even though the preimage is not unique, it does not matter, because there is no way for $b,b'\in B$ with $b\neq b'$ to make $\phi(a)=b=b'$ true, because $\phi$ is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniqueness of preimage matters in the first case, but not in the second.

In the first case, you want to define $\psi$ so that $\psi(\phi(a)) = a$. If there were $a \ne a'$ such that $\phi(a) = \phi(a')$, then it wouldn't work because $\phi(a) = \phi(a')$ implies $\psi(\phi(a)) = \psi(\phi(a'))$ so $a = a'$.

However, in the second case, uniqueness of preimage does not matter. You want to define $\psi$ so that $\phi(\psi(b)) = b$. Now the $\psi(b)$ occurs directly in the formula. (In the first case, there was no $\psi(a)$, only $\psi(\phi(a))$). So you just need to pick any $a$ such that $\phi(a)=b$, and set $\psi(b)=a$.

Comment: oh! so it is not about the definition of function, it is about the composition I finally want. Great thx!

Comment: Well, it is about the definition of function. In the first case, if $a \ne a'$, and $\phi(a) = \phi(a') = b$, then if you follow the argument, $\psi(b)$ would have the two distinct values $a$ and $a'$. But this doesn't happen in the second case - you can simply pick any preimage, because $\psi(b)$ is directly in the formula you want.

Comment: Ah-ha! Ok I get you. In the first case it can be $\psi(\phi(a))=a'$. Thanks for the explanation!